# Error saying attempting to reference a deleted function while using a copy_if in map

Tags: c++

Когда я пытался реализовать метод для поиска пар, содержащих некоторый текст, я столкнулся с ошибкой компиляции, которая говорит:

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\algorithm(585):
>   error C2280: "std::pair &std::pair::operator =(volatile const std::pair &)": attempting to reference a deleted function while using

Мой код:

```
map<string,string> dict;    
string srch_wrd;
    bool pred_name(string str) {
        bool res = 0;
        if (str.find(srch_wrd) != -1)
            res = 1;
        return res;
    }
    void find() {
        map<string, string> buff;
        cout << "Enter keyword" <<endl;
        cin >> srch_wrd;
        copy_if(dict.begin(), dict.end(), buff.begin(), [](auto const& obj) {return (pred_name(obj.first)&& pred_name(obj.second)); });
        for (auto i = buff.begin(); i != buff.end(); i++)
        {
            cout << i->first << " - " << i->second << endl;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`copy_if` здесь работает примерно вот так:

```
auto it = buff.begin();
for (...)
{
    if (...)
    {
        *it = ...;
        it++;
    }
}
```

Тут есть две проблемы.

- Во-первых у элементов в `map` константные ключи.

  `*buff.begin()` возвращает ссылку на `pair<const string, string>`, и
  из-за этого `const` что-то вроде `*buff.begin() = ...;` - не
  компилируется.
- Во-вторых, даже если бы не было предыдущей проблемы, `copy_if` перезаписывает существующие объекты, а не создает новые.

  Третий параметр должен показывать на уже существующие объекты, а
  `buff.begin()` ни на что не показывает, потому что мапа пустая.

---

Решение - использовать [`std::inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter).

```
#include <iterator>

// ...

copy_if(dict.begin(), dict.end(), inserter(buff, buff.begin()), ...);
```

Comment: Да, заработало, только в inserter надо ещё указывать итератор на начало вставки.

Comment: @VadimMatiuhin Точно, поправил.